# Why is it called MagSafe?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I still get confused sometimes at the name MagSafe. Has it anything to do with the magnet in it? Why MagSafe? is it safer than other adapters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magnet can save your computer.

Let's suppose it's on a table connected to AC. If someone pull the cable with his foot by just walking by, the MacBook won't fall on the floor, the magsafe will just pop.

Comment: You're right man, I've thought about that many times and it has actually happened one or two times. The name does makes sense after all. It's just that I've never thought too deep about the name and always thought it was MacSafe and not Mag, only when I actually wrote the question here did it really occur to me that it is Mag as in magnet.

Answer (score 5):

This is well answered by Wikipedia’s article on [MagSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magsafe).

Summary: to obviate expensive repairs to connectors and laptops when users tripped over their power cords, Apple designed a connector that would stay connected *mag*-netically under normal circumstances, but which would *safe*-ly disconnect when the power cords (or laptops) were suddenly pulled away.

Comment: That's just brilliant innovation.